# Refresh jQuery mobile listview after ajax

Tags: listview, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to refresh a jQuery mobile list view after an ajax post, I have been trying to use the .trigger("create") to do this like so:

```
<div data-role="content">


<div id="linksHolder" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a id="most-played" href="#" data-role="button" data-mode="mostplayed">Most Played</a>
    <a id="latest-added" href="#" data-role="button" data-mode="latestadded">Latest Added</a>
    <a id="featured" href="#" data-role="button" data-mode="featured">Featured</a>
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Mode)
<ul class="video-list" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true"></ul>

</div><!-- /content -->


<script class="videoTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl"> 
    <li data-theme="c">
        <a href="${LinkToVideo}">
            <img src="${ThumbnailPath}" alt="video 1" />
            <div class="title">${Title}</div>
            <div class="description">${Description}</div>
            <div class="additional-details">
                <b>Category:</b> ${Category}<br />
                <b>Contributor:</b> ${Contributor}
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    DrawPageContent();

    // function to redraw the page content with the mode passed
    $(document).on("click", "#linksHolder a", function () {
            //alert("Inside link");
            var mode = $(this).attr("data-mode");
            $("#Mode").val(mode);
            DrawPageContent();
    });

    // Renders the JSON data into HTML and displayed through a jQuery template
    function DrawPageContent() {
        var mode = $("#Mode").val();
        var jsonUrl = "/mobile/GetVideos?mode=" + mode;

        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': jsonUrl,
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                // Render the videos using the template
                $(".video-list").html($(".videoTemplate").tmpl(data));
                $(".video-list").trigger("create");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I also tried using $('.video-list').listview('refresh'); but this didn't work either. It is refreshing the JSON data fine, but it is not applying the jquery mobile CSS classes, thus I am losing the listview styles. Any thoughts??

Thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can see what your selectors point to.

Comment: Hi Calavoow, I have edited the post to display the HTML and jQuery template. Thanks

Comment: In your code <ul> tag is incompleted

Comment: Hi Harry - just a formatting mistake when editing the code on the post. This tag is completed. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using a jQuery template to format your code you could try and only create a listview of titles without using the template plugin. Another tip: You can use jQuery's .getJSON(..) command to fetch JSON with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this still would not help my situation would it because it still needs to refresh the jquery mobile listview after the ajax post? This is because jquery mobile adds classes to the elements such as 'ui-li-thumb' which is what I am losing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to this was that DrawPageContent() was not being called when the document was ready. Once this was changed I could use .listview("refresh"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    DrawPageContent();
});

$(document).on("click", "#linksHolder a", function () {
    var mode = $(this).attr("data-mode");
    $("#Mode").val(mode);
    DrawPageContent();
});

function DrawPageContent() {
    var mode = $("#Mode").val();
    var jsonUrl = "/mobile/GetVideos?mode=" + mode;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': jsonUrl,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            // Render the videos using the template
            $(".video-list").html($(".videoTemplate").tmpl(data));
            $(".video-list").listview("refresh");
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use id instead of class because you can use this class in multiple control so try id of your tag as per given below

```
<ul id="vdo_list" class="video-list" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true"></ul>

$("#vdo_list").listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the post. I did try this previously against the class... Even with the ID, I get "TypeError: $("#vdo_list").listview is not a function" - I am using jquery 1.7.2 and jquery mobile 1.1.1 (latest versions)

Comment: You can apply id vdo_list in ul?

Comment: Please try something like this `$(".video-list").listview('refresh');`